# Bash: Assign output of command group to variable

Tags: bash

While it is possible to assign the output of a shell command to a variable like so:

```
list=$(ls -la)
```

It seems that I cannot assign the output of a command group to a variable. This here seems not to work:

```
output=${ echo "Peter"; echo "Pan"; }
```

But: Piping the output of a command group [1] is possible:

```
{
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "From: $FROM"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJ"
 echo
 echo "Please check $HOSTNAME"
} | ssmtp $MAILTO
```

Why can't I assign the output of the command group to a variable?

---

[1] Command group:  `{ ... } | ...`

See: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html

Comment: `$(...)` is not just a subshell `(...)` prefixed with a `$`; it is a distinct piece of syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are using curly braces:

```
$ output=${ echo "Peter"; echo "Pan"; }
bash: ${ echo "Peter"; echo "Pan"; }: bad substitution
```

Inside curly braces, `${...}`, bash expects the name of a variable.

To capture the output of a command, use parens:

```
$ output=$( echo "Peter"; echo "Pan"; )
$ echo "$output"
Peter
Pan
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it. - Now, can this construct `$( ... )` span several lines? Like in my example with `ssmtp`? // Checked it in the terminal: It can. -- But: Where is the difference btw a command group and `$( ... )`?

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Use `$(...)` when you want to capture the output assign it to a variable.  Use `{...}` when you want to pass the output on in a pipeline.

Comment: @Ugur Note that it's entirely possible to use a command group *inside* of a command substitution: `output=$({ echo "Peter"; echo "Pan"; })`. But (at least in simple cases like this) it's rather pointless.